# php-excel.class.php collect data foreach row

Tags: php

https://code.google.com/p/php-excel/
I'm trying to get all the same numbers(for test purposes here) in one row:
So in the end my desired result is:
H1 # H2 # H3
1 # 1 # 1
2 # 2 # 2
3 # 3 # 3

That's what my PHP looks like and I need to output it in a form ($data) the class will understand (and in best case generate it automatically/dynamically for the number of existing column-arrays ):

```
$head=array("H1","H2","H3");
$column1=array();
$column2=array();
$column3=array();

for($i=1;$i<=3;$i++){
   $column1[]=$i;
   $column2[]=$i;
   $column3[]=$i;
}
```

Expected PHP-Example from the Class which I don't know how to generate:

```
$data = array(
        1 => array ('Name', 'Surname'),
        array('Schwarz', 'Oliver'),
        array('Test', 'Peter')
        );

// generate file (constructor parameters are optional)
    $xls = new Excel_XML('UTF-8', false, 'My Test Sheet');
    $xls->addArray($data);
    $xls->generateXML('my-test');
    */
```

Answer (score 0):

NYOS_ExcelWriter_simple 1.0 seems to be much easier to use and the output is more predictible:

```
// data array
    $array = array();

    // 1 string
    $tr = array();
        // 1 colum
        $tr[] = 'one';
        // 2 colum
        $tr[] = 'two';

    $array[] = $tr;

    // 2 string
    $tr = array();
        // 1 colum
        $tr[] = '2 one';
        // 2 colum
        $tr[] = '2 two';

    $array[] = $tr;
```

http://www.phpkode.com/source/s/nyos_excelwriter_simple/example.php
http://www.phpkode.com/source/s/nyos_excelwriter_simple/excel_simple.php

Comment: Problem with Umlaute solved here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30326764/php-to-excel-german-umlaute/30332580#30332580