# Encoding chinse, arabian, inidan, russian caracters write in excel php

Tags: php, excel, character-encoding

I am exporting some db fields into excel using php, The thing is that i want to be able to export all characters no matter of language (arabian, chinese and so on)

my write into excel cell function looks like

```
function label($value) {
    $value = mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UTF-16', mb_detect_encoding($value));
    $length = strlen($value);
    $this->data .= pack("ssssss", 0x204, 8 + $length, $this->row, $this->col, 0x0, $length);
    $this->data .= $value;
}
```

and it woks with german german characters and others but not with arabian, chinese :(

Do you know what do i have to modify?
$value = mb_convert_encoding($value, 'UTF-16', mb_detect_encoding($value));
needs an upgrade but I can not find anything useful.
Any tips?

Comment: mb_strlen() has no effect

Comment: Please provide a short, self contained, correct example http://sscce.org/ or a link to where your complete approach is described. I suspect your approach creates BIFF4 rather than up to date BIFF versions. So the problem with the umlauts results from the fact that the older Excel BIFF formats uses Windows encodings rather than Unicode. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30326764/php-to-excel-german-umlaute/30332580#30332580.

Comment: i think you are right. I am using https://gist.github.com/ihumanable/929039